# font styles not working when set custom font for webview

Tags: android

Main.java:

```
Main instanceMain = this;
    String Dataz = FN.getHtmlData(instanceMain,"BMitra",20,(getResources().getString(R.string.matn2)));
    btne.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", Dataz, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

FN.java:

```
public static String getHtmlData(Context context,String fontname,Integer fontsize, String data){
    String head = "<head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: 'MYFNT';src: url('"+fontname+".ttf');} body {text-align:justify;font-family: 'MYFNT';color: Black;}</style></head>";
    String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body dir=\"rtl\">"+data+"</body></html>" ;
    return htmlData;
 }
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="matn2">
    <![CDATA[
    <html><body><b>سلام</b> non bold text . <b>english bold</b></body></html>
    ]]>
</string>
```

but **bold** tag not working and output is : سلام english bold . non bold text

by the way i found [some report issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=SharedPreferences&colspec=ID%20Type%20Version%20Security%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=30520)

---

in another way :

Main.java :

```
Main instanceMain = this;
    String Dataz = FN.getHtmlData(instanceMain,getResources().getString(R.string.matn2)));
    btne.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", Dataz, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

FN.java:

```
public static String getHtmlData(Context paramContext, String paramString)
  {
    return "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang=\"fa-ir\" dir=\"rtl\"><head>" + "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"justified_textview.css\" />" + "</head>" + "    <body>" + paramString + "</body></html>";
  }
```

justified_textview.css (in assest folder) :

```
/*@font-face {
font-family:"MyFont";
src:url('file:///android_asset/BMITRA.TTF');
}

@font-face {
font-family:"MyFont";
src:url('file:///android_asset/BMITRABD.TTF');
font-weight: bold;
}*/

@font-face {
font-family: 'Conv_BMITRA';
src: url('file:///android_asset/BMITRA.ttf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Conv_BMITRA';
src: url('file:///android_asset/BMITRABD.ttf');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}


body {
font-family:'Conv_BMITRA';
text-align:justify;
line-height: 20pt;  
color: Black;      
}
```

and matn2(strings.xml) :

```
<string name="matn">
    <![CDATA[
    م ولادت توی وب با سی اس اس
    normal text
    <b>ولایت بولد م bold text</b>
    ]]>
    </string>
```

and now its work on android 2.3.3 or 2.3.5 but **not working** on android 4.0.x

Comment: Have you tried to style it via css?

Comment: @Flo yes.and not working.by the way,when write
.boldClass{text-weight:bold}
in css,aapt.exe has stopped working and crashed.

and even write this: b{text-weight:bold} in css,its not working again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, because of Webview rather than Android OS progress, is broken. If you set a custom font for Webview, in some device and Android OS it works and in some others not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue on a really large page I was displaying.  Try setting the activity with the webview to `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the manifest.

Comment: what's associated with the webview? can you explain more?

Comment: I'm not sure specifically how webview is effected by hardware accelerated drawing, but there are some functions that aren't supported with hardware acceleration.  Here is more info on that: [Android Hardware Acceleration](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html).  Some of the functions that aren't supported or are known to behave differently are related text drawing.