# Can't get custom fonts to work in WebView Android

Tags: java, android

I have been on this for hours and no matter what I do I am not able to use a custom font in the WebView which I need to display arabic in .

My code is simple ..

```
        WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

     //view.loadData(getHtmlData(this," شسيشسياسيشسيحمد"), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
     view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,getHtmlData(this," شسيشسياسيشسيحمد"),"text/html","utf-8",null);


private String getHtmlData(Context context, String data){
    String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'feast';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/droidnaskh_regular.ttf');}body {font-family: 'feast';}</style></head>";
    String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body style='font-size:30px;'>"+data+"</body></html>" ;
    return htmlData;
 }
```

This is all . I have tried a million different ways to achieve this , sometimes changing the URL of the reference file , sometimes using it with loadData instead of loaddatawithbaseurl , but nothing gives.

Please help me . I am using JB .

My generated HTML is

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face 
            {font-family: 'feast';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/droidnaskh_regular.ttf');}
        body 
        {font-family: 'feast';}
    </style>
</head>
<body style='font-size:30px;'> 
        شسيشسياسيشسيحمد
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you seen in logcat that if it shows with html??

Comment: @PiyushGupta . I just added the HTML that this code generates

Comment: I'm not sure but are you using the right encoding scheme. Because I've used similar code in my project and it worked for me !

Comment: @gauravsapiens were you using JellyBean too ? .

Comment: Somebody have problem same (RTL URDU)  before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401219/font-styles-not-working-when-set-custom-font-for-webview