# Howto stop the linear layout to scroll with the webview?

Tags: android, web-applications, webview

I have a webapp with the following structure.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Webview>
    <LinearLayout>
      <Button>
```

What I want is to scroll the webview, but the Linearlayout should not scroll as I am drawing a canvas over it.

When I run the app in emulator I can achieve it, but the same app when I run it on device, the layout scrolls with the webview.

So when the webview scrolls down I cannot draw on it.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Can you paste your full xml code please.

Comment: Put the LinearLayout outside the WebView. WebView isn't meant to have child Views.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull the `<LinearLayout>` tag from inside of the `<Webview>` tag, and put it on outer.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But if you mean something else in the UI, please draw it and attach it to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. I had a webview which contained linearlayout with a button. Now I have separated the webview from linearlayout. However I cannot understand why was it working on emulator though

Comment: @user3680974 Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13008643/421467 . And if the answer helped you, please set it as the answer and if you liked it, vote it up too. Thanks.